# Replacing multiple characters from a single string in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

Is it possible to replace multiple characters from a string in Visual Basic, like for example:

```
mary had a little lamb
```

All letter `a` must be changed to `z`,
all `m` must be changed to `y`,
all `t` must be changed to `x` 
in just one line of code?

Comment: For a single replacement you can use `text = Replace(text, "a", "z")`. Repeat that for all replacements and you have solved the problem, but it will be more than one line of code. If you have a lot of different replacements, put them in an array and loop through it. Still not one line of code, though.

Answer (score 5):

As the result of `Replace` is a string, you can concatenate multiple replacements:

```
Dim s As String = "mary had a little lamb"
Dim t As String = s.Replace("a", "z").Replace("m", "y").Replace("t", "x")
Console.WriteLine(t) ' outputs "yzry hzd z lixxle lzyb"
```